# How can I save as the document as .psb file using win32com.client in python?

Tags: python, photoshop, win32com

In photoshop and using python, I cannot save the active document as PSB (Large Document Format) file

With win32com.client, I can save active documents as .psd files like this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

psApp = Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
activeDocument = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument
activeDocument.SaveAs("E:\\PSDCopy", PhotoshopSaveOptions, False)
```

Though I cannot force it to save as psb no matter what I tried.
I also could not find any clue in the VBScript documentation, now even a word about psb files.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe created a terrible API for interfacing with Photoshop. Worse than that, the documentation is deprecated and doesn't include updates like PSB files, EXR files etc.

A good way to find out how to write code for that is to use the Photoshop ActionListener and hack your way around (doesn't always work but it gives you some good leads). You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2006/05/installing_and_1.html).

This should do what you are looking:

```py
import comtypes.client as ct


app = ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.Application')


def save_as_psb(path):
    """ Save the current Document as PSB with maximised compatibility
    turned ON.

    Args:
    path (str): This is the filename of the output PSB
    """

    desc19 = ct.CreateObject("Photoshop.ActionDescriptor")
    desc20 = ct.CreateObject("Photoshop.ActionDescriptor")
    desc20.putBoolean(app.StringIDToTypeID('maximizeCompatibility'), True)

    desc19.putObject(
        app.CharIDToTypeID('As  '), app.CharIDToTypeID('Pht8'), desc20)
    desc19.putPath(app.CharIDToTypeID('In  '), path)
    logging.debug(path)
    desc19.putBoolean(app.CharIDToTypeID('LwCs'), True)
    app.executeAction(app.CharIDToTypeID('save'), desc19, 3)
```

Comment: For the recent versions of PS listener script needs to be downloaded from [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html). Also install instructions are changed. This is like 'introduction to cryptology'.

Comment: @ArdaKutlu indeed, the way Photoshop is exposing it's actions isn't always straightforward. Sometimes, even if you completely copy and paste the listener, you won't be able to execute it in different Photoshop versions. In that case I suggest, first saving the function you want to test through `Photoshop->Scripts` menu and if it works, use the `REPL` of Python to execute it line by line and debug :)

Also feel free to *upvote* my answer, if that was helpful to you :) Ta

Comment: for some reason, I cannot make it work with win32com.client. The reason I want to use that is when frozen with pyinstaller it needs only a 10mb additional space. whereas comtypes library takes nearly 500mb additional space. More importantly, I couldn't make comtypes work when frozen with pyinstaller. I would love to upvote but seems like my reputation is not high enough to make it publicly visible.

Comment: No worries about the upvote. I am going to send you another version that works with `win32com`!

Comment: I just made it work with win32com.client as well. Unlike from comtypes.client, methods in Dispatches starts with a capital letter. In comtypes: `desc19.putObject` becomes `desc19.PutObject` with win32com Thank you very much

Comment: No problem! Exactly the are some minor differences but `comtypes` and `win32com` are pretty similary in functionality. I am actually writing an Open Source library to interface Photoshop with Python. It should be available soon in my GitHub repo @wizofe on PhotoPie repository. I think it's important for the community so feel free to send additions :)

Comment: can any one share java script version of above code ?